# Bus to wire in quartus

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I sometimes run into a problem with altera's Quartus that I would like a better solution to. Sometimes I use the graphical interface for design and I have a bus that I would like to pull off just one route it to a block. Usually I create a custom block and put one wire in and multiple wires out. This seems a little excessive, is there a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just connect it up directly with a wire (you will see a little blob appear to show it is connected). Then, name the bus something like `name[msb..lsb]`, and then name the wire `name[whichbit]`. That will tell Quartus to connect them because they both have the same name and tell it which bit it should connect to. You will get errors if you choose a `whichbit` which is less or more than the `msb` and `lsb` of the bus.

Better still, don't bother with the schematic and wire it all up in a Verilog (or VHDL) file.

Comment: I can only partially agree with the last sentence. I usually prefer code because it is easier to create, modify, maintain, share etc., but a well drawn top level block schematic is definitely something which a big project should have.

Comment: @VladimirCravero I agree with that - generally all my projects have a single top-layer schematic, but it is usually nothing more than input/output pins and a single main module.